# Problem with HTML inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am trying to implement 'time-ago' feature in my website using a JQuery timeago plugin. Unfortunately I have encountered some problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
jQuery("abbr.timeago").timeago();
</script>

var content = document.getElementById('div');

var html = "<abbr class=timeago title=2008-07-17T09:24:17Z></abbr>" + '<br>';
content.innerHTML += html

<div id='div'></div>
```

This jquery plugin basically convert timestamp from the title and print it in a nice format for every abbr class=timeago. The problem is that the code above doesn't work, but if I put it within this div it works fine. I think it is maybe because this jquery plugin is applied before generating html by javascript, but I am not sure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It's better to use jQuery.timeago(timestamp) function than deal with abbr and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The problem, I bet, is that your statement that initializes the "timeago" plugin is running *before you put the `<abbr>` element into the page*. Therefore, when it runs, nothing happens.

Why would you add to the DOM with that primitive code when you've got jQuery anyway?

```
$('#div').append($('<abbr/>')
  .addClass('timeago')
  .attr('title', '2008-07-17T09:24:17Z')
).append($('<br/>')).append($('<br/>'))
.find('abbr.timeago').timeago();
```

(I'm assuming that you really do have a `<div>` element with the "id" value "div".)

The statement:

```
$('abbr.timeago').timeago();
```

means, "find all `<abbr>` elements with the class "timeago", and initialize the "timeago" plugin on each of them."  It does **not** mean, "any time there's an `<abbr>` element on the page, and it has the class "timeago", well then make sure that the "timeago" plugin is set up for it."

Comment: Well the reason I am doing this is that I use it within a loop, I have multiple tomeago divs with several different dates. Your code would surely be easier and more elegant, but it is not what I need.

Comment: If you run the code at the end of the page (or within a $(document).ready() function), it *will* execute for every matching element on the page (in this case, any `<abbr>` with the class of "timeago". Really, all you need is to make sure you have an ISO8601 timestamp in the title"" attribute. http://timeago.yarp.com/

Comment: Yes, but note that in the original question the element is being *added* to the page dynamically by Javascript.

Comment: @Vafello well I still suspect that your fundamental problem is that you need to call that "timeago" initialization **after** you add the stuff to the page, not before.

Comment: But with the current code, is it possible to call jquery plugin after the JS is executed?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be?  jQuery is just Javascript. You can call it any time you want to. It certainly won't work if you just call it beforehand.

Comment: Yeah, but I am not sure how to do it. I wont work if I simply place the code at the end of this html file. Maybe my questions are silly, but I am new to JS. Thanks.

Comment: Well where is the code that adds the "timeago" sections?  Why not just do the jQuery plugin setup right at the end of that?

Comment: Well it would help a lot if you'd post more of your code then.

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = "<abbr class=timeago title=2008-07-17T09:24:17Z></abbr>" + '<br><br>';
```

First off, put your attributes in quotes:

```
var html = "<abbr class=\"timeago\" title=\"2008-07-17T09:24:17Z\"></abbr>" + '<br><br>';
```

Also, refer to this page: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_abbr.asp

The point of the ABBR tag is to give additional information regarding an inline element for crawlers and the like. I'm hard-pressed to think of a reason you might want to use this for a datetime.

I'd say rather than crawling through a plugin you don't know very well trying to find out why it likes divs rather than abbr's, just use the div. If it has to be an inline element, use `<span>`.

Comment: Quotes aren't always required (and aren't in this case) in HTML.  That shouldn't be the problem, although it is good practice to use them all the time. http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2

Comment: Thanks, I didnt use quotes just for testing purposes because I thouth it might cause the problem. Anyway, I changed it to div, that's fine but it doesn't solve the problem:/